# netlogo: Check whether a certain turtle is ahead of current moving turtle

Tags: shapes, netlogo, turtle-graphics

A. In NetLogo, I want to check which type of turtle is ahead of the current moving turtle. I try to do this through looking at the shape or color of the turtle ahead. Context: i want the moving turtle to check whether it meets a moving enemy, if so, the moving turtle should avoid the moving enemy

I tried this line as condition:

```
if [color] of turtles-on patch-ahead 0 = yellow [do this]
```

B. And I would like to check whether a certain turtle is overlapping the current moving turtle with this code as condition.

```
if [color] of turtles-here = yellow [do this]
```

It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't do as intended.

Comment: `patch-ahead 0` means the same as `patch-here`, so `turtles-on patch-ahead 0` reduces to just `turtles-here`, and that probably isn't what you meant.

Comment: You're going to need to decide what you want the definition of a turtle being "ahead" of another turtle is. For example, you might want to check out the `in-cone` primitive.

Comment: the context is that i want to check whether the moving turtle meets a moving enemy so the moving turtle can avoid the moving enemy, i will update this in my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[color] of turtles-here
```

returns a list of colors. yellow returns a number. So you're comparing a list with a number rather than a number with a number.

I think you'd like:

```
if any? turtles-here with [color = yellow] [do something]
```

Comment: thanks! this solves the second problem. do you have a suggestion for the first problem? :D

Comment: What is the first problem? I'm unsure of the question at hand.

Comment: to check whether the turtle, ahead of the moving turtle, is yellow, if so, do this

Comment: you mean turtles-here to turtles-here patch-ahead right?

Comment: Just replace the agent set of the agents you want to check against. So change turtles-here to turtles-on patch-ahead 1

Comment: but when i say 'if any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 with [color = yellow]' it highlights the '1' and says 'WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a number instead'

Comment: You need parens: `if any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with ...`